# Appropriate labels for multiple times entry fields

Tags: forms, mobile-application, labels, mobile-text-entry

I am working on an app where the user can book a service and can select upto 3 occurrence of that service per day. This means the user needs to be prompted to enter three distinct times of the day. I am wondering how I should label the time fields.

At first go, "Time 1" , "Time 2" ... comes to mind but for sone reason it doesn't feel right.

What would be the recommended way to label the time fields?

PS: This may not be relevant to the question but I am going to put the "Time fields" as individual rows instead of cramming them all into one row (as shown in the picture), perhaps also because there could be more than 3 times per day in the future and the overall look of the form.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a field set for the time input. One way to do it could be to choose a field - set heading, such as 'Walk times'. Under this heading, you can show multiple fields as per the user's chosen frequency.

For labels, it's probably best to keep the context of the walks. So the labels could just be:

#### Walk Times

- First walk:                      2:00pm
- Second walk:                6:00pm

However, if the user chooses a frequency of one, you might want to keep things simple and show a simple 'Walk time' label for a single input (hide other bits).

Comment: thanks. I thought of that too but since the number of walks is dynamic and is controlled by the back end i think I will have to code some sort of logic to render the words "First", "Second", "Third" and so on in case a frequency of more than 1 is selected.